# Do I have to copy libraries to jniLibs every time I update them (Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I learned about JNI files through this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0vL7-_xuDM

After lots of experimentation I have figured out that in order to link a C file to Android it seems that I need to

1. Create an application.c file in a "jni" directory outside my src directory
2. Create Android.mk and Application.mk files, also in he "jni" directory
3. Run "ndk-build" in a terminal to create lib___.so files in a "libs" directory
4. Copy these lib___.so files to a "jniLibs" folder under src/main
5. In my activity, load the library I created in the c file
6. Include an unimplemented native method that I call whenever I want to get my data

My problem is that whenever I want to change anything in my C application I need to repeat steps 3 and 4 to run ndk-build (again) and then copy the newly updated files in the "libs" directory into the "jinLibs" directory (again), in order to show anything new in my activity. This seems redundant and unnecessary. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you already managed to compile your jni sources with `ndk-build`. Now, the "manual part", i.e. copying libs/files can be accomplished fairly easy via a `gradle task`. After the native build task you could add a 'copyTask', like this:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask ->
    compileTask.dependsOn buildNative // building via NDK
    doLast{
        // ...
        copyLibs
    }
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'pathToJNILibs'
}
```

For the sake of completeness, I would further add some cleanup tasks to avoid hassling with old files